# DLNA app for Android like "Play To" in Windows Phone

Tags: android, dlna

I have a Chinese Android phone and a WiFi enabled Sony Bravia TV. Though the Chinese android phone has an app for display mirroring, it is unreliable and sometimes doesn't work. So I want an app which can send music photo and videos to the TV wirelessly. Just like "Play To" which works flawlessly in my Lumia 520.

It would be better if the app doesn't also support online videos services or such things and/or is free. I like simplicity. :P

Answer (score 3):

I use **[BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)** for that:

- works smoothly
- can stream from your device to your TV (can even act as "control point", i.e. you don't need to navigate from your TV – just select it in *BubbleUPnP* and tell it to "play it there")
- can also act as client (to play media from other UPnP/DLNA services on your device)
- full (payed) version ([license](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp.unlocker) to obtain separately) enables Internet streaming – which you don't want. So perfect: free version is available, and doesn't really offer that :)
- support for smartphones and tablets alike (below screenshots are the smartphone GUI; see the linked *Google Play* page for tablet screenshots).

[image: BubbleClient] [image: ControlPoint]
<sup>*BubbleUPnP* as client (left) and server/controlpoint (source: Google Play; click images for larger variants)</sup>

For alternatives, I might point you to [my listing of UPnP/DLNA apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=79). I've not tried them all, as I'm pretty satisfied with *BubbleUPnP* as an all-in-one solution (server, client, and control point) – but you have the options :)